# Highchart Legend with Checkbox, events, hover style, symbol order change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I currently have Highcharts implemented in a `Chart` component in my application, but I need to make some changes to the Legend, went through most of the documentation, created some functions with `Highcharts.wrap()`.

First, the Legend was simple, each legend item being

`[Symbol] [Label]` .
[image]

But now I need to change it into:

`[Checkbox] [Label] [Symbol]`
[image]

Here is what I got so far:

`[Checkbox] [Symbol] [Label]`
[image]

And with the click on the checkbox replicating the click on the Legend (symbol, label), which shows/hide the series line.

how? with this: (showing only the important parts)

```
const defaultOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    ...,
    legend: {
        borderColor: "transparent",
        verticalAlign: "top",
        align: "left",
        x: 14,
        itemCheckboxStyle: {
            cursor: "pointer",
            border: "1px solid #62737a",
        },
    },
    ...,
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            ...,
            showCheckbox: true,
            selected: true,
            events: {
                checkboxClick: function () {
                    this.setVisible(!this.visible);
                },
            },
        },
        ...,
    },
...,
}
```

If we only use `showCheckbox: true`, the checkbox will be far on the right side of each label, not ideal. So this is needed: (*If possible I also would like tips on how to avoid the **any** error on TS in this case, without the comments*).

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Legend.prototype, "positionCheckboxes", legendCheckboxPosition);
function legendCheckboxPosition(
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    this: any,
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    p: any,
    scrollOffset: number
) {
    const alignAttr = this.group.alignAttr;
    const clipHeight = this.clipHeight || this.legendHeight;
    let translateY: number;

    if (alignAttr) {
        translateY = alignAttr.translateY;
        Highcharts.each(
            this.allItems,
            function (item: {
                // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
                checkbox: any;
                // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
                legendItem: { getBBox: (arg0: boolean) => any };
                // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
                checkboxOffset: any;
            }) {
                const checkbox = item.checkbox;
                const bBox = item.legendItem.getBBox(true);
                let top;

                if (checkbox) {
                    top = translateY + checkbox.y + (scrollOffset || 0) + 2;
                    Highcharts.css(checkbox, {
                        left:
                            alignAttr.translateX +
                            item.checkboxOffset +
                            checkbox.x -
                            100 -
                            bBox.width +
                            17 +
                            "px",
                        top: top + "px",
                        display: top > translateY - 6 && top < translateY + clipHeight - 6 ? "" : "none",
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

***But with this done, I still need to make some changes, which are:***

1. Change the order of **Symbol** and **Label**
   There is supposed to be a `rtl` property inside the `legends` options, which is supposed to change the order of **Symbol** and **Label** , but if I do that, it reverses, but it also reverse the order of the legends somehow, I'll show:
   -> Without `rtl`:
   [image: without rtl option being true]

-> With `rtl: true` inside the `legends` options:
[image]

The checkbox distance I understand, because it will need to change my `legendCheckboxPosition` function, my real problem here is the order of the legends being changed, like if I used `legend.reversed: true`.. I found out that I can use the `reversed` property to fix this, but I was wondering if this was a bug with something else..because in the documentation the `rtl` property only changes the order of **Symbol** and **Label**, not the legends order.

This is what I need: [image]

2. I need to put a style in the `:hover` of the checkbox, I tried using the `legend.itemCheckboxStyle` but that doesn't allow me to add **hover** effects... (I need to place a box-shadow when hovering the checkbox)

- **ONE ISSUE SOLVED**: Another issue is when clicking the legend item (which is separated of the checkbox)
  When clicking the legend item, it shows/hide the series, but it doesn't change the checkbox selection.
  I know that the checkbox selection is determined by the `series.selected` property, and that I have the `legendItemClick` event inside the `plotOptions.series.events`, but inside that I don't have a `this.setSelected` function, only `this.setVisible` function. I tried using that, but it seems to freeze the chart, not doing anything.
  How to change the checkbox selection when clicking only in the legend item?

**Edit**: Managed to solve this by adding this event to `options.plotOptions.series.events` :

```
legendItemClick: function () {
    const seriesIndex = this.index;
    this.chart.series[seriesIndex].select();
},
```

Well.. that is my problem, with the hope that you guys can help me solve it.

Comment: Just found out that the `rtl` property of the Series.Legend is supposed to work properly only with 1 series, I tried on the [Highcharts api example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/rtl/) and adding 1 more series there also revert the series order...

Comment: Hi, please simplify what you want to achieve now and a basic example of your case will be helpful.

Comment: Hi @SebastianHajdus , I added some images to try to examplify, I know it's complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and experimenting, I managed to have it all working.

**Options** (default options and events, also toggling visibility on load)

```
const series = GetSeries(opts, null);
...
// Check if Series is supposed to be hidden from load (from the checkbox selected prop), if it is, hide it
series.forEach((serie) => {
    if (serie.selected !== undefined && serie.selected === false) serie.visible = false;
});

const defaultOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    ...,
    legend: {
        borderColor: "transparent",
        verticalAlign: "top",
        align: "left",
        x: 14,
    },
    ...,
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            ...
            showCheckbox: true,
            selected: true,
            events: {
                checkboxClick: function () {
                    this.setVisible(!this.visible);
                },
                legendItemClick: function () {
                    const seriesIndex = this.index;
                    this.chart.series[seriesIndex].select();
                },
            },
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
};

return mergeObjects(defaultOptions, opts);
}
```

And a lot of resolved **extending Highcharts**:

```
// Adjust position of the Highchart Legend Checkbox, and switch label and symbol in the legend
function legendPositionAdjustments(
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    this: any,
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    p: any,
    scrollOffset: number
) {
    const pixelsToREM = (value: number) => {
        return value / 16;
    };
    const alignAttr = this.group.alignAttr;
    const clipHeight = this.clipHeight || this.legendHeight;
    let translateY: number;
const legendMainElement = this.box.parentGroup.element;
// Adjust the main legend element to be closer to the checkbox
if (legendMainElement) {
    Highcharts.attr(legendMainElement, "transform", "translate(19, 10)");
}
if (alignAttr) {
    translateY = alignAttr.translateY;
    this.allItems.forEach(function (item: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        checkbox: any;
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        legendItem: { getBBox: (arg0: boolean) => any };
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        checkboxOffset: any;
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        legendGroup: any;
    }) {
        const bBox = item.legendItem.getBBox(true);

        // Change position of Label and Symbol in the Highcharts Legend
        const legendItemElement = item.legendGroup.element;
        const legendItemPath = legendItemElement.querySelector("path.highcharts-graph");
        const legendItemPoint = legendItemElement.querySelector("path.highcharts-point");
        const legendItemText = legendItemElement.querySelector("text");
        if (legendItemPath) {
            Highcharts.attr(legendItemPath, "transform", `translate(${bBox.width + 3}, 0)`);
        }
        if (legendItemPoint) {
            Highcharts.attr(legendItemPoint, "transform", `translate(${bBox.width + 3}, 0)`);
        }
        if (legendItemText) {
            Highcharts.attr(legendItemText, "x", 0);
        }

        // Adjust the position of the checkbox to the left side of the Highcharts Legend
        const checkbox = item.checkbox;
        let top;
        let left;
        if (checkbox) {
            top = translateY + checkbox.y + (scrollOffset || 0) + 4;
            left = alignAttr.translateX + item.checkboxOffset + checkbox.x - 100 - bBox.width + 17;
            Highcharts.css(checkbox, {
                left: pixelsToREM(left) + "rem",
                top: pixelsToREM(top) + "rem",
                display: top > translateY - 6 && top < translateY + clipHeight - 6 ? "" : "none",
            });
        }
    });
}
}

// This function is called when triggering show/hide of series, always calling with visibility = true
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any, @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
function colorizeLegendRegardlessOfVisibility(this: any, proceed: any, item: any, visible: any) {
    proceed.call(this, item, true);
}
```

This will:

- Avoid changing the color of the legend and symbol when series is hidden or legend is out of focus
- Correct position the checkbox to left side of the legend
- Switch positions of the symbol and label, which are in the SVG

Hope to help someone who encounters similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to arranging the elements of legend would be to edit the legend in `legend.labelFormatter` and add a Unicode line character. To have the checkbox on the right also you can style it in `legend.itemCheckboxStyle`.

```
  legend: {
    symbolWidth: 0,
    useHTML: true,
    labelFormatter: function() {
      return `<div>${this.name}<span style="color: green;">&#9473;</span></div>`;
    },
    itemDistance: 50,
    itemCheckboxStyle: {
      "width": "13px",
      "height": "13px",
      "margin-left": "-130px",
      "position": "absolute"
    }
  },
```

API References:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.itemCheckboxStyle

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sbcL7rp9/3/

Comment: This is a great solution, I had tried it, but the problem with it was that the color needs to be the same as the series color, so it can't be static. I'll post the solution I found